# Getting page not found error while access API with Django rest token authorization

Tags: python-3.x, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am trying to access a get method API with the token and I check in the Django rest framework token authentication document and I followed the same, I could not find the error, while login with superuser token is generating successfully and using that token trying to access the API but getting error like mentioned below. if anyone suggests me what is the mistake I made.

```
Not Found: /hello/ 'Authorization :  token 52de5dee105764e92d5d6c644919b4aafec489ab'
[05/Jul/2020 12:36:15] "GET /hello/%20'Authorization%20:%20%20token%2052de5dee105764e92d5d6c644919b4aafec489ab' HTTP/1.1" 404 2429
Not Found: /hello/ 'Authorization: Token 52de5dee105764e92d5d6c644919b4aafec489ab'
[05/Jul/2020 12:39:05] "GET /hello/%20'Authorization:%20Token%2052de5dee105764e92d5d6c644919b4aafec489ab' HTTP/1.1" 404 2419
Not Found: /hello/ "Authorization: Token 52de5dee105764e92d5d6c644919b4aafec489ab"
[05/Jul/2020 12:39:43] "GET /hello/%20%22Authorization:%20Token%2052de5dee105764e92d5d6c644919b4aafec489ab%22 HTTP/1.1" 404 2413



#Setting.py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',  # <-- And here
    ],
}

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'atoken',
]

#URLS.PY
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token
from atoken import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-token-auth/', obtain_auth_token),
    path('hello', views.HelloView.as_view(), name='hello'),
]


#VIEWS.PY
class HelloView(APIView):

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request):
        content = {'message': 'Hello, World!'}
        return Response(content)


#While login with superuser got the token mentioned bellow

{
    "token": "52de5dee105764e92d5d6c644919b4aafec489ab"
}


  #so Added in the usr like bellow `enter code here`

http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/ 'Authorization:  token 52de5dee105764e92d5d6c644919b4aafec489ab'

http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/ "Authorization: Token 52de5dee105764e92d5d6c644919b4aafec489ab"

#Tried both single and double quotes but same error.
```

Comment: how did you pass the token to Django? in URL?

Comment: like this   http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/ "Authorization: Token 52de5dee105764e92d5d6c644919b4aafec489ab"

Comment: could u pls help me

Comment: It generally works this way `"Authorization: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"`. You need not mention "Token" again unless you are using a custom authentication class.

Comment: there are 3 double quotes you have mentioned, is it  like this "Authorization": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

Comment: I tried like this http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/  "Authorization:  52de5dee105764e92d5d6c644919b4aafec489ab"  but the same error

Answer (score 1):

in postman, we should not access like bellow format

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello "Authorization: Token 52de5dee105764e92d5d6c644919b4aafec489ab"
```

it does not work so we have sent the token in the header like this way image mentioned bellow

And it worked for me.

[image]

Reference to create Django rest token authentications,
I followed the bellow links and finally created Django rest framework token authentication.

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/11/22/how-to-implement-token-authentication-using-django-rest-framework.html

https://medium.com/quick-code/token-based-authentication-for-django-rest-framework-44586a9a56fb

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a forward slash in you url path.Update it with this:

```
path('hello/', views.HelloView.as_view(), name='hello')
```

Comment: That also tried the same error http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello// 'Authorization: Token 52de5dee105764e92d5d6c644919b4aafec489ab'

Comment: Are you passing the Token in the headers?

Comment: like in the link mentioned above http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello// "Authorization: Token 52de5dee105764e92d5d6c644919b4aafec489ab"

Comment: because it is get method

Comment: I followed this tutorial  https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/11/22/how-to-implement-token-authentication-using-django-rest-framework.html

Comment: are you still getting Not Found error after updating URL path?

Comment: Yes still getting, pls help me

Comment: Post the exact url command you are hitting on terminal.

Comment: not on terminal i am using in postman and in browser the url is the same http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello// "Authorization: Token 52de5dee105764e92d5d6c644919b4aafec489ab"